# Laravel/Eloquent: calculated database field in model how

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, field

(Question posted on Laracast too, didn't reveal any answer yet, so I give Stackoverflow a try)

Hi community,

I have to solve a database problem in Eloquent with a model which has a field which is to be read from different databases. Since I have difficulties expressing my problem properly in English/OOP/Laravel/Eloquent/PHP terminology, I'll try to express my needs in an example (don't care much about correct PHP syntax).

Given there is a model resembling a tree-like structure, attributes used are usually:

```
[treenode]
id
parent_id (=self referencing key to id)
name
...
```

Now say the tree is to store pointers to nodes of different kinds, say, houses, cars and users, each of which is stored in a different table/model:

```
[house]
id
name
street address
zip
...

[car]
id
name
brand
horsepower
...

[user]
id
name
age
gender
...
```

The problem is obviously to have a model for "treenode" which transparently accesses the other databases to populate the "name" field, which all the models have in common, to draw the tree.

I thought about changing the treenode model to:

```
[treenode]
id
parent_id
kind (house | car | user)
data_id (key into house | car | user table)
...
```

The next step was to "somehow" code the "name" field in Eloquent, so it appears like it still was part of the "treenode" model, and this is where I am stuck. I tried a "calculated field" inside the model, like described in the docs, like so:

```
public function name() {

select case $this->kind {
    case house: return House::findorfail($this->data_id)->first()
    case car: return Car::findorfail($this->data_id)->first()
    case user: return User::findorfail($this->data_id)->first()
}
}
```

This does work somehow at first glance, but obviously "name" isn't really included in the model's attributes list, so it doesn't get serialized, i.e. if I JSON_encode a treenode, "name" is not included.

And a similar problem arises when setting "name" by changing a treenode, if the name is to be changed, I'd have to write it back into the correct database, and JSON support was also required. I have no clue how I could achieve this. I read about accessors, like getNameAttribute and setNameAttribute but as far as I have seen they work only if there is a "name" field in the treenode model.

Can anyone point my nose into the right direction ... can I somehow rework my treenode model so it incudes a "name" field which gets its contents from the other tables, and, if I asssign a value to it, writes the name into the other tables, but otherwise behave exactly like when it was included in the "treenode" model?

Thx,

Armin.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: V5.4, sorry, I forgot to mention. But I already saw your proposed answer, and this seems really promising. I'll give it a try tonight, and let you know about the outcome ASAP. In the meantime: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From reading problem it seems that laravel's `Polymorphic Relations` are the right answer for your problem, since you can link a model with different models and not "harcode" the type of the model as a foreign key.

Since polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model on a single association.

Check this out with example:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: This seems the way to go, but it seems that Ross beat you by some seconds to give the answer. Nevertheless, thanks very much for your input, seems that this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Test first, then cheer :-) Upvote coming, promised :-)

Answer (score 0):

From your example it sounds like you're after [Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

Firstly, change `data_id` and `kind` to `kind_id` and `kind_type` i.e.

`data_id` becomes `kind_id` and

`kind` becomes `kind_type`

you can do this in your migrations file with:

```
$table->morphs('kind');
```

Then in your `treenode` model add:

```
/**
 * Kind Relationship
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
 */
public function kind()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

/**
 * Get the name from the "kind" relationship
 * 
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->kind->name;
}
```

Then you could do the following:

```
$treeNode = App\TreeNode::with('kind')->first();

$treeNode->name; //This would be the name on the other model
```

(The above assumes that you `treenode` model is `App\TreeNode`. If it isn't then simply change it to whatever is correct).

### Edit

If you're already working with a production environment / need to keep your data as is then you will need to update the `kind_type` to be the fully qualified namespace of the model that it's referencing e.g.

```
DB::table('treenode')
    ->where('kind_type', 'user')
    ->update(['kind_type' => \App\User::class]);
```

You will need to do this for all the different `kind_type`s (you should only need to do this at the beginning, after that when you use the `associate()` method this will happen automatically).

Alternatively, you can set up a morph map:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
    'user' => 'App\User',
]);
```

You can add the above to the `boot()` method in your `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: Hi Ross, not much luck so far. Two problems: first, I changed the models like you suggested, but the Treenode model still does not seem to include a "name" attribute, which was one of the goals I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Moreover, there seems to be a serious problem with namespaces, my models are not found. I get this error: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'user' not found in [...]\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php:487. I tried to put an use App\User statement into my controller as well as into the Treenode model file, and I can, in both files, successfully query any user model, e.g. $test=User::find(6), nevertheless the error persists when I call $node->kind->name from the controller.

Comment: Do you change your table column names as well? Make sure you're following PSR-1 and PSR-4 e.g. the class name matches the file name exactly and they are written in StudlyClass i.e. `User.php` and `class User` not `user`.

Comment: I Followed your instructions exactly. Column names are "kind_id" and "kind_type", and all that does kinda work, if I query $node->kind->name on a node of kind_type = "user", the "user" model cannot be found, if i set kind_type to "house", the messacge changes to class "house" not found. The morph does address the correct model, but fails to find it. It looks like a problem with namespaces and scopes. The models are OK, since I can successfully query each model in the controller as well as in the "Treenode" model.

Comment: Any model is affected, for my demo I choose the (unchanged) "user" model provided by Laravel's auth component to rule out any problem with my own models.

Comment: @Nimral I've added an update to my question which should help :)

Comment: Hi Ross,

I appreciate your skills, and say thanks for trying to help me out, but it seems things are getting more and more quirky. I found an easier solution, which serves me well, without all the hassles: I put a dummy "name" (string[0], nullable) in my treenode table, and intercept all reads and writes using an accessor and a mutator in my treenode model, and redirect them to the correct child database.
Think this is a quite clean and easy to handle solution.